# take information from github readme.md

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World
```

There is a repository, I need to take content from `readme.md` file.

I've found

```
https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/readme
```

but the content is in `base64` encoding.

How can i get normal text?

Comment: I need to take content by axios.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert base64 to content using `atob`

```js
axios
  .get("https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/readme")
  .then(({ data: {content} }) => {
    console.log(atob(content));
  });


console.log(atob("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhCg==\n"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```